# Receive SMS to Android app without opening the app at least once

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to receive SMS from my android app. I have following receiver specified in my manifest.

```
<receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.lahiruchandima.myapp.SMSReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

SMSReceiver successfully receives SMS if my app is installed and opened once (app does not need to be running at the moment the SMS is received to the device). But, if i do not open my app at least once after a fresh install, it doesn't receive any SMS.

Does anybody know a way to make it possible to receive SMS without opening the app at least once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does anybody know a way to make it possible to receive SMS without opening the app at least once?

It can't be done, on newer Android versions at least. Ever since Android 3.1, apps are installed in a *stopped state*, and require that the user open it at least once before components like your BroadcastReceiver can function. This is for security reasons, to prevent, or at least hamper, malicious program behavior.

Comment: Here's one, in the section "Launch controls on stopped applications", about two-thirds of the way down: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html. "Applications are in a stopped state when they are first installed but are not yet launched...", "Note that the system adds `FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` _to all broadcast intents_."

Comment: Alright cool, thanks for the heads up. So it is not possible to register a push notification receiver and get a push notification before the application is launched for the first time